# How to make Apache recognize domain when connecting through SSH tunnel?

Tags: apache, ssh

I have an Apache server which is using name-based virtual hosts.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost
    ServerName localhost.localdomain
    ServerAlias localhost.localdomain
    ErrorLog logs/localhost_error_log
    CustomLog logs/localhost_access_log common
    <Directory /var/www/localhost1>                           
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost1.localdomain
    ServerAlias localhost1.localdomain
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost1
    ErrorLog logs/localhost1_error_log
    CustomLog logs/localhost1_access_log common
    <Directory /var/www/localhost1>                           
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type localhost.localdomain and localhost1.localdomain I get the proper pages from the folders /var/www/localhost and /var/www/localhost1 respectively. But then I do

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:10080:localhost.localdomain:80 -L 0.0.0.0:10081:localhost1.localdomain:80 localhost
```

And localhost:10080 and localhost:10081 both result in the answer from /var/www/localhost. Is it possible to make Apache recognize the domains despite connecting through SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to match the Apache vhost ServerName with what you type into your browsers address bar.

Assuming this vhost:

```
ServerName foo.com
```

Then in your local /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1  foo.com
```

Then

```
ssh -L8080:127.0.0.1:80 user@apache
```

Then

```
wget http://foo.com:8080
```

Now the request is made with Host: foo.com and it should hit the correct vhost.

Comment: localhost1.localdomain:10081 works fine - many thanks :)